# Linking Java Code changes to functional tests

Tags: java, testng, functional-testing, integration-testing

The code is set of java restful apis.
We have huge set of functional test cases[700+] using testng to test the different flows.
The features are continuously being added and so test cases will be more in future.

I have a scenario where if we are changing or touching a small piece of code, we need to identify which all tests which need to run for testing a piece of code.
Running all the test cases takes time and sometimes there are failures in validations due to other components which are not touched by us. So these failures validations takes further time.

Is there a way to identify the subset of tests or do some mapping from api/method to test case.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way of programmatically figuring that out since it depends on the "_context of the change_". Since you know what exactly is being tested when you write them, perhaps you could [group the tests into categories, functionalities or something similar](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups), and execute only the tests related to the group that is considered as "_being changed_".